# Limit what Azure AD groups are visible to oauth app

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I use a service on the web that needs to map an Azure AD group to a set of users with a specific role.

However once the service asks to be able to read the Azure AD groups, so I can chose what Azure AD group should map to a specific role, it has access to all my Azure AD groups.

Is there any way I can limit what Azure AD groups the service can see? I want to limit that on my end and not as a filter on their end. I can't find any documentation on it.

The service uses the Azure AD Graph API to fetch the groups.

Comment: You should probably use administrative units https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/administrative-units

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best practices for using role-based access control in groups:
[image]

please check this document for more information:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/fundamentals/identity-management-best-practices#use-role-based-access-control

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Mehtab, but you kind of miss the question. I am well aware of RBAC, and that is actually also what I am doing here. 
My problem is that the app I use can see ALL my groups. I only want it to see the groups that are relevant to that app.